# How do I send parameters using MonoTouch.ObjCRuntime.Selector and Perform Selector

Tags: c#, iphone, ios, xamarin.ios, monodevelop

Here is an example I found, but they omitted actually sending the params.

```
this.PerformSelector(new MonoTouch.ObjCRuntime.Selector("_HandleSaveButtonTouchUpInside"),null,0.0f);

[Export("_HandleSaveButtonTouchUpInside")]
    void _HandleSaveButtonTouchUpInside()
    {
...
}
```

I would like to be able to do something like this:

```
this.PerformSelector(new MonoTouch.ObjCRuntime.Selector("_HandleSaveButtonTouchUpInside"),null,0.0f);

[Export("_HandleSaveButtonTouchUpInside")]
    void _HandleSaveButtonTouchUpInside(NSURL url, NSData data)
    {
...
}
```

How do I change the PerformSelector Call to send params to the method?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The [MonoTouch docs](http://iosapi.xamarin.com/?link=M%3aMonoTouch.Foundation.NSObject.PerformSelector%28MonoTouch.ObjCRuntime.Selector,MonoTouch.Foundation.NSObject,System.Double%29) indicate that method maps to the Obj-C selector [`performSelector:withObject:afterDelay`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSObject_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSObject/performSelector%3awithObject%3aafterDelay%3a), which only supports invoking a selector with a single argument.

The best way to handle this depends what you need to do. One typical way to handle this would be to put the arguments as properties/fields on a single NSObject, then the target would be modified to have a single argument, and pull the real arguments off that method. If you did this with a custom MonoTouch object, you'd have to watch out for the GC collecting the managed peer, if nothing in managed code kept a reference to it.

A better solution would depend on exactly how you're using it. For example, in your example, you could trivially call the C# method directly, e.g.

```
_HandleSaveButtonTouchUpInside (url, data);
```

If you need to dispatch via Obj-C for some reason, but don't need the delay, use [MonoTouch.ObjCRuntime.Messaging](http://iosapi.xamarin.com/?link=M%3aMonoTouch.ObjCRuntime.Messaging.void_objc_msgSend_IntPtr_IntPtr%28System.IntPtr,System.IntPtr,System.IntPtr,System.IntPtr%29), e.g.

```
MonoTouch.ObjCRuntime.Messaging.void_objc_msgSend_IntPtr_IntPtr (
    target.Handle,
    MonoTouch.ObjCRuntime.Selector.GetHandle ("_HandleSaveButtonTouchUpInside"),
    arg0.Handle,
    arg1.Handle);
```

If you need the delay, you could use an [NSTimer](http://iosapi.xamarin.com/?link=M%3aMonoTouch.Foundation.NSTimer.CreateScheduledTimer%28System.TimeSpan,MonoTouch.Foundation.NSAction%29). MonoTouch has added special support for this to use an [NSAction](http://iosapi.xamarin.com/?link=T%3aMonoTouch.Foundation.NSAction) delegate, so you can use a C# lambda to capture arguments safely.

```
NSTimer.CreateScheduledTimer (someTimespan, () => _HandleSaveButtonTouchUpInside (url, data));
```

Comment: Thank you for the thorough answer mhutch.  I have been using PerformSelector when I needed to free up the main thread so that cocoa would redraw the screen, and then i could get back to processing some logic.  Right now I am trying to update the equivalent of a progress bar which has been drawn to the screen during a writeStream for loop I have.  Wanted to see if I could essentially refresh the screen by putting a perform selector within the for loop and updating the property of the progress bar.

Comment: Another way to do that would be to use a thread for the logic/stream, and use InvokeOnMainThread from the thread to update the UI.

Comment: This saved me from having to manually rebind a library because the original developer didn't bind a particular property, or release the source, so thank you. For anyone interested, properties can easily be set using the msgSend_IntPtr_IntPtr method by calling setColor: where color is the name of the property. (Arg 0 is the property value, Arg 1 = IntPtr.Zero)

Comment: It's been a while, and I don't see Messaging any more under ObjCRuntime in Xamarin.Mac. Is there a replacement I can use?

Answer (score 4):

I could not find the binding for this call either.  In the sample below I added my own overload for PerformSelector.  Maybe one of the Xamarin Engineers can confirm this.

```
using System;
using MonoTouch.Foundation;
using MonoTouch.UIKit;
using MonoTouch.ObjCRuntime;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace delete20120506
{
    [Register ("AppDelegate")]
    public partial class AppDelegate : UIApplicationDelegate
    {
        UIWindow window;

        public override bool FinishedLaunching (UIApplication app, NSDictionary options)
        {
            window = new UIWindow (UIScreen.MainScreen.Bounds);

            // 
            Target target = new Target ();
            NSUrl url = new NSUrl ("http://xamarin.com/");
            NSData nsData = NSData.FromString ("Hello");

            target.PerformSelector (new MonoTouch.ObjCRuntime.Selector 
                                  ("TestSelUrl:withData:"), url, nsData);

            window.MakeKeyAndVisible ();

            return true;
        }
    }

    [Register ("Target")]
    public class Target : NSObject
    {
        public Target () : base (NSObjectFlag.Empty) {}

        [Export("TestSelUrl:withData:")]
        void TestSelUrlWithData(NSUrl url, NSData nsData)
        {
            Console.WriteLine ("In TestSelUrlWithData");
            Console.WriteLine (url.ToString ());
            Console.WriteLine (nsData.ToString ());
            return;
        }

        [DllImport ("/usr/lib/libobjc.dylib", EntryPoint = "objc_msgSend")]
        public static extern void void_objc_msgSend_intptr_intptr_intptr (IntPtr receiver, IntPtr selector, IntPtr arg1, IntPtr arg2, IntPtr arg3);

        [DllImport ("/usr/lib/libobjc.dylib", EntryPoint = "objc_msgSendSuper")]
        public static extern void void_objc_msgSendSuper_intptr_intptr_intptr (IntPtr receiver, IntPtr selector, IntPtr arg1, IntPtr arg2, IntPtr arg3);


        public virtual void PerformSelector (MonoTouch.ObjCRuntime.Selector sel, 
                                              NSObject arg1, NSObject arg2)
        {
            if (this.IsDirectBinding)
            {
                void_objc_msgSend_intptr_intptr_intptr (this.Handle, 
                    Selector.GetHandle ("performSelector:withObject:withObject:"),
                    sel.Handle, arg1.Handle, arg2.Handle);
            }
            else
            {
                void_objc_msgSendSuper_intptr_intptr_intptr (this.SuperHandle,
                    Selector.GetHandle ("performSelector:withObject:withObject:"), sel.Handle, 
                    arg1.Handle, arg2.Handle);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Awesome overloading of the Monotouch Selector!  I may try this one in my project holmes.  Thank you for sharing.  I hope that people that are looking for PerformSelector will fall on this question.